# Procedurally Create-Generate a Raster Image with PyQt

Tags: python, image, qt, pyqt, raster

What would be a short simple way to generate a raster image with PyQt? Ideally I would like to supply a function with a desired image resolution (such as 16x16 pixels) and save the resulted image to drive as a simple JPG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [QImage](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html) class:

```
def create_image(width, height, path):
    img = QtGui.QImage(width, height, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
    img.fill(QtCore.Qt.red)
    img.save(path, 'JPG')
```